# window scroll don't work properly

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code JS

```
var elem3 = document.createElement('DIV');
elem3.setAttribute('id', 'eye');
elem3.style.display = "block";
elem3.style.width = "100px";
elem3.style.height = "100px";
elem3.style.zIndex = "301";
elem3.style.position = "absolute";
elem3.style.top = "0px";
elem3.style.left = "0px";
document.body.appendChild(elem3);
var danger, up = 0;
window.onscroll = function(e) {
    up += 10;
    document.getElementById('eye').style.top = up + "px";
}

function check() {
    danger = setInterval(function() {
        if (document.getElementById('eye').style.top >= 2000 + "px") {
            location.href = "http://www.google.com";
            clearInterval(danger);
        }
    })
};
check();
```

I want to create a div (eye) and with scroll I want that this div fall by 10px.1 scroll=10px, 10 scroll=100px. If the top of eye is greater then 2000px this will redirect the page. But this don't work because when I begin scroll, the page redirect automatically and the div don't scroll to 2000px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (document.getElementById('eye').style.top>=2000+"px"){
```

That check is wrong, the check is a string comparison, not a number comparison.

You should be using parseInt to get the number value of the position.

```
if (parseInt(document.getElementById('eye').style.top,10)>=2000) { ...
```

Why are you checking the style when the variable `up` should hold the value?

```
if (up>=2000){ ...
```

Comment: you were faster than me. +1

Comment: Thanks for the tip variable increases: D, now i want a function that check this variable and when reach the value, do the action i want.

Comment: yes i solved.I replaced parseInt.... with the variable up.Am i stupid?Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `window.onscroll=function(e){up+=10;document.getElementById('eye').style.top=up+"px";}`

1) use `scrollTop` and added delay in `setInterval`.

2) Your "if" not work, use `integer` instead of `string`

Try this:

```
var elem3=document.createElement('DIV');
elem3.setAttribute('id','eye');
elem3.style.display="block";
elem3.style.width="100px";
elem3.style.height="100px";
elem3.style.zIndex="301";
elem3.style.position="absolute";
elem3.style.top="0px";
elem3.style.left="0px";

document.body.appendChild(elem3);

var danger, up=0;
window.onscroll=function(e){
    up = window.scrollTop() + 10; //or `up = window.scrollTop();`
    document.getElementById('eye').style.top = up +"px";
};

function check(){
    danger = setInterval(function(){
        if (parseInt(String(document.getElementById('eye').style.top).replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g)) >= 2000){
            location.href="http://www.google.com";
            clearInterval(danger);
        }
    }, 100);//Added delay
};

check();
```